# PHP: chr Function Issue with Special characters

Tags: php, utf-8, chr

In PHP i have the following code:

```
<?php
  echo "€<br>";
  echo ord("€") . "<br>";
  echo chr(128) . "<br>";
```

And i get the following output:

```
€
128
�
```

Why can't the chr function provide me the € sign? How can i get the €? I really need this to work. Thank's in advance.

Comment: I need the actual € sign inside a string.

Comment: what is the file saved as, UTF-8 (with/without BOM)? could be the issue. Save it as ANSI and all 3 echos will appear correctly.

Comment: It's saved as an UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: When using UTF-8, `ord('€')` returns `226` instead of `128` (the latter is the Latin 1 decimal code)

Comment: I was getting 226 rather than 128 for the second one, so something doesn't pan out here, when saved as UTF-8 (with/without BOM).

Comment: Ok created a new file and converted with notepad++ and it gives me 226.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chr` and `ord` only work with single byte ASCII characters. More specifically `ord` only looks at the first byte of its parameter.

The Euro sign is a three byte character in UTF-8: `0xE2 0x82 0xAC`, so `ord("€")` (with the UTF-8 symbol) returns 226 (0xE2)

For characters that are also present in the ISO-8859-1 (latin1) character set, you can use `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()`, but unfortunately the € sign is not contained there, so `utf8_decode('€')` will return "?" and cannot be converted back.

**TL;DR:** You cannot use `ord` and `chr` with a multi-byte encoding like UTF-8